# How to get the Microsoft SQLCLR Stored Procedure Example to work

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I'm new to CLR and am struggling with the Microsoft tutorial already.
This is the Tutorial: [How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx)

There is an example stored procedure Insert_Currency_CS and a test.sql

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;


public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [SqlProcedure()]
    public static void InsertCurrency_CS(
        SqlString currencyCode, SqlString name)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context   connection=true"))
        {
            SqlCommand InsertCurrencyCommand = new SqlCommand();
            SqlParameter currencyCodeParam = new SqlParameter("@CurrencyCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

            currencyCodeParam.Value = currencyCode;
            nameParam.Value = name;

            InsertCurrencyCommand.Parameters.Add(currencyCodeParam);
            InsertCurrencyCommand.Parameters.Add(nameParam);

            InsertCurrencyCommand.CommandText =
                "INSERT Sales.Currency (CurrencyCode, Name, ModifiedDate)" +
                " VALUES(@CurrencyCode, @Name, GetDate())";

            InsertCurrencyCommand.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();
            InsertCurrencyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
EXEC InsertCurrency 'AAA', 'Currency Test'
SELECT * from Sales.Currency where CurrencyCode = 'AAA'
```

To get this to work I have to add the AdventureWorks2014 I guess, so I just added it as new Database Project into my solution can copypasted its content (tables and 2 scripts) into my First Project Database inside of the solution explorer. But then I get Syntax Errors and not recognized option errors in my Deployment Script CLRTest.sql at for example these lines:

```
GO
:setvar DatabaseName "CLRTest"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "CLRTest"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Users\Torsten\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\CLRTest"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\Users\Torsten\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\CLRTest"
```

The first :setvar line I get the syntax error and DataBaseName is not a recognized option. Similarly here

```
:on error exit
```

and here

```
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
```

Now can maybe someone explain me how to make my Database project use the AdventureWorks2014 database, so that the tutorial CLR stored procedure is working when being executed by the test.sql.

I guess the problem is that I don't know how to put the AdventureWorks2014 database into my empty database project. I am trying SQLSchemaCompare now, then update Target (localdb)\ProjectsV12.CLR Test. Here I have the problem, that if I include AW2014FullTextCatalog in the Upgrade, I receive the an script execution error, and if I exclude it, I get an error in another script CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON...
Additionally this error:

> Error 1   SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>   Msg 9982, Level 16, State 100, Line 1 Cannot use full-text search in user instance.
>   C:\Users\Torsten\AppData\Local\Temp\CLR Test_1_Update3.publish.sql    47  1

I'm not even sure is this is the right way to put a database into an empty database, the MS tutorial wasn't even up to VS2013 but only VS2010...

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: What does `CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG` have to do with anything? Did you copy-paste the wrong thing? Or did you maybe forget a `GO` somewhere that causes this statement to be considered part of the previous one?

Comment: Error:  SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [AW2014FullTextCatalog]
    WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON
    AS DEFAULT
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo];

Comment: That's not an error returned by SQL Server, it's the error returned by the SSDT deployment process. The real error should be buried in the output window somewhere, you may have to increase the verbosity. Or, if you want to take a shortcut, find the full-text catalog in the database project and delete it -- it's part of Adventure Works, but not relevant to testing how CLR stored procedures work.

Comment: Ok I got several in correct syntax errors in my Deployment script for the Database project. Maybe someone can just tell me, how to get this tutorial CLR stored procedure running with adventureworks2014 in my Database project, this is my actual question.

Comment: Have you been able to get a regular SQL stored procedure to work in your SSDT project yet?  That should really be a prerequisite before moving on to something advanced/specialized like a CLR stored procedure.

Comment: Nope I haven't. The reason why I started with CLR C# stored procedure directly is because we want to develop a SQL server addin and we want to use CLR C# for that, which didn't know before. :)

Comment: Sometimes the best option is to get a friend that knows what he/she is doing to sit with you at the computer.....   You don't seem to have basic skills in fault finding or isolation, hence you are not able to ask a detailed enough question to get help.

Comment: My question is clear enough, how to get this Microsoft tutorial to work as it should lol.

Comment: @user26026 If the question were clear, then others wouldn't be asking for clarification. Also, it is difficult to deem a question as being "clear" when it is stated that an error is occurring and yet the specific (and full) _SQL Server_ error message has not been included in the question.

Comment: I guess the problem is that I don't know how to put the AdventureWorks2014 database into my empty database project. I am trying SQLSchemaCompare now, then update it with Target (localdb)\ProjectsV12.CLRTest. Some Error is popping up but most tables were updated, yet they don't appear in project explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no knowledge of SQLCLR, and are even unfamiliar with "SQLCMD mode" in SSMS / Visual Studio (hence the syntax errors on lines starting with `:setvar`), then you should not be starting with the Microsoft examples. For example, the tutorial linked in the question even states, at the top:

> This documentation is archived and is not being maintained.

So, clearly the tutorial page isn't being read very carefully and any number of things could be going on here, possibly related to version differences in SQL Server, Visual Studio, etc. Or, there could be prerequisite steps for doing the Microsoft tutorials that haven't been followed.

Instead, you should review the series of articles I am writing on working with SQLCLR on SQL Server Central:

[Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/)

Free registration is required to view content on that site, but it is well worth it as there is an incredible amount of free information related to working with SQL Server.

The series on SQLCLR that I am writing guides you through what exactly SQLCLR is and isn't, what it can (and can't) do, what the differences are between SQL Server's CLR host environment and the Windows CLR host (i.e. the "regular" .NET environment) and the fact that SQLCLR operates more like a Web App than a Console App / WinForm App.

The examples in my articles are step-by-step with full explanations of what is going on. Working Assemblies are provided for the first several articles as one shouldn't be messing with creating SQLCLR objects until there is a basic understanding of the environment, given the restrictions and nuances of working within SQL Server that could be dangerous if you just start creating SQLCLR objects without having any basis for understanding what you are doing and if you should even be doing it.

After that, *then* (maybe) take another look at the Microsoft examples. But it could very well be that either you don't need SQLCLR (i.e. T-SQL is just fine), or perhaps you can't do what you want in T-SQL but doing it in SQLCLR won't work due to the environmental constraints.

---

With regards to the out-dated tutorial you are working on, I don't see why you are trying to include the `AdventureWorks2014` in your Visual Studio / SSDT project. You should be able to ignore the existing schema / objects and just publish to it.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look. Well actually a friend of me has more knowledge, but he's busy and got sick (too much stress in his SD job) right now and yesterday evening the Skype shared monitor didn't work, so I as a curious person wanted to take a look myself and get some first knowledge, so I just hit on the MS Getting Started Pages. In our project he's the guy with the MSSQL and .NET knowledge and I am there for the algorithms. And as I never set up a Server project I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong maybe.

Comment: @user26026 Based on what you are saying and what you are trying to do: **1)** I have updated my answer with some clarification and some additional info, and **2)** I _highly_ recommend that both you _and_ your friend / coworker review that series on SQLCLR that I linked to before attempting to make any more progress on this Microsoft tutorial.

Comment: Hi the recommended version of the tutotial actaully says the same: "The following code example creates a stored procedure that inserts a record into the Currency table of the Adventure Works sample database." The stored procedure InsertCurrency_CS is inserting in Sales.Currency, which is a table of Adventure Works. So if I execute InsertCurrency by test.sql I guess I need Adventure Works, because it is being adressed by InsertCurrency_CS.

Comment: I think my friend is working with CLR in his job for a while already... he just didn't have time yet (since yesterday) to help me (he got fever right now) and I don't wanna waste time and prepare myself. We both studied and graduated as MA in Mathematics and he already was been working as developer while studying while I didn't, I just have background in algorithms and several programming languages, but didn't really use much more than SQL. (no TSQL etc)

Comment: @user26026 I think you are jumping in way too far way too fast. You have a lot of basics to cover before working on advanced topics, and this is an advanced topic. Even if you get this tutorial working, you will still have almost no idea what you are looking at or if any of this applies in any way to your problem. This is not an insult; I'm just trying to help you out. I'm not questioning your ability to learn this stuff, just advising that based on your experience, you have a lot to learn about SQL Server and SSDT projects first. (continued...)

Comment: @user26026 If you don't know T-SQL that well, then you definitely should not be attempting SQLCLR. And I didn't say that you don't need AdventureWorks, just that you don't need it in your project. If you aren't sure of the difference between a database not being in your project and a database not existing in an instance of SQL Server, you need to find some other tutorials to first get up to speed on SQL Server, how it is structured, how VisualStudio / SSDT work, etc.

Comment: Hi thx for your help. Well ok it works when we just move the stored procedure into the SQL Server Express Adventure Works and set the Debug Target Connection String of the VS Project to SQLExpress Adventure Works. What doesn't work yet is importing the Adventure Works database into the empty VS project, then add the stored procedure and the test.sql and run it in localdb. It seems just to import .sql for CREATE TABLE not the actual tables themselves...maybe that's because it's just a localdb instance? Have to google for that now. :)

Comment: @user26026 Are you using both SQL Server Express _and_ SQL Server Express LocalDB? Also, again, why are you importing AdventureWorks into a project in the first place?

Comment: HI, sorry for my late answer,  the localDB is the default connect debug target connection string. What I actually wanted to do is to use AdventureWorks in my Visual Studio as a complete database, I thought this is possible. If I change the connection string to SQLExpress I am using the AdventureWorks in my SQLExpress, but I thought if I have the AdventureWorks in my VS Project localDB I don't have to copy the CLR stored procedures and execute them in my SQL Management Studio but can execute them conveniently in VS.

Comment: I just found this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2012/02/02/including-data-in-a-sql-server-database-project/